# Box2D destroying body Causes: failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, box2d, physics-engine

Ive been working with libgdx box2d physics engine lately, and i am making moving bodies, in which i need to destroy those bodies after they are offscreen. So when i destroy them i got this error:

> failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled

Solutions i tried:

> ulimit -c unlimited (in terminal)

I am on mac, and i am using android studio to code.

The error occurs only if i destroy the body.

code for loop:

```
 public void updateMapGen(float delta, OrthographicCamera cam) {
        this.update(delta);
        // loop through all the blocks, each block has a box2d body
        for (Block b : blocks) {
            // check if the body is off camera
            if ((b.body.getPosition().x * PPM) + b.getWidth() < cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2) {
                // destroy the body. Error doesnt come at a specific line, but removing this line fixes the error
                b.destroy();
                blocks.removeValue(b, true);
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("BLOCKS: " + blocks.size);
    }
```

code for destroying the body:

```
public void destroy(){
   body.getWorld().destroyBody(body);
}
```

Comment: Have your restarted Java

Comment: I have similar set up in which I have a class that inside has Box2D the same. You might want to remove block from array of blocks first before destroying a body; swap those two lines might be.

Comment: Is updateMapgen called while your world step() is executing? Body removal should be done outside of this, and best practices are to mark your body as "dead" and then remove many bodies at once outside of the step() call. Also, your destory() method is, is one line, using body to get the world and then destroying the body itself. Off the top of my head unsure if there is a circular dependency there. If you alter your code to just call world.destroyBody(body) on its own (get a reference to world before the call), does that help? Also removing elements of a collection inside a foreach loop is bad

Comment: @PeterR I tried getting the world from its main instance, i still got the same error, as for the destroying, its being called in an update method which is called before rendering and stepping. So you want be to put my Bodies in an array called dead, then remove them after a certain amount of time?

Comment: destroy your object when world is unlocked. `if(!world.isLocked()){  }`

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Same error, didnt work :/

Comment: @Liwaa break loop after `blocks.removeValue(b, true);` statement

Comment: @AbhishekAryan i cant, i want the loop to finish, this is because i want to check for every block if its no longer appearing

Comment: @Liwaa I suspect AbhishekAryan is onto something. Basically I suspect that `b.destroy()` is freeing memory that's going to be needed still if you continue the loop.

Comment: @Liwaa Continuing from my last comment... given that you want to check every block and not just destroy the first found, seems you need your loop to build a separate collection of the blocks you want to destroy and then have a second loop iterate over the to-be-destroyed collection to actually destroy them. And then reset `blocks` to the collection of blocks remaining. Or something like this to avoid dereferencing memory that's being invalidated.